# Extract out lines with "s__" into a new file together with first two lines of the file

Tags: command-line

I have a [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CdoBmClQIW3vWGTxZFq_KRc0_ZMGL8W1/view?usp=sharing) from where I want to extract the first two lines (starting with "ID" and "#SampleID") along with all the lines that contain "s__" in that line. And, want to put them in a new file. Can anyone please tell me how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'NR<3 || /s__/' yourfile > newfile
```

or

```
sed -n -e '1,2p' -e '/s__/p' yourfile > newfile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -m2 "" your.file > test.txt; grep "s__" your.file >> test.txt
```